# Laravel 4: insert with max+1 in laravel

Tags: laravel, insert, max, eloquent

I want to run the following query

```
INSERT INTO static_pages (`page_name`, `title`, `page_display_order`) SELECT 'test','test', MAX(page_display_order)+1 FROM static_pages;
```

How to execute this query with laravel eloquent? Is that possible?

**Update**

Thanks @Joseph Silber

I used this in elaquant as like

```
$staticpage->page_display_order = DB::raw("($subquery)");
$staticpage->save();
```

That helped to get the last inserted id.

Comment: No, it's not possible with Eloquent and MySQL. You need full raw query for that.

Comment: ok. Thank @JarekTkaczyk . So. how else i can do this. First take the `$max = DB::table('static_pages')->max('page_display_order');` in first query and use that number in array to insert in the table as such like `$final_arr['page_display_order'] = $max+1;`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DB::raw()` with a subquery:

```php
$subquery = DB::table((new StaticPage)->getTable() . ' as page_alias')
              ->selectRaw('page_display_order + 1 as pdo')
              ->orderBy('page_display_order', 'desc')
              ->take(1)->toSql();

StaticPage::create([
    'page_name' => 'test',
    'title' => 'test',
    'page_display_order' => DB::raw("($subquery)"),
]);
```

Comment: It won't work, you can't pass aggregate function as a value from the same table in MySQL. Only way would be `insert into TABLE(..) select VALUE1, VALUE2, max(..) from TABLE;`

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - Oh yeah. Completely missed that. Updated.

Comment: @JosephSilber I tried but this shows the below error `General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'static_pages' for update in FROM clause` and the query generated for this is `(SQL: insert into `static_pages` (`page_name`, `title`, `page_display_order`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (testingfinal, testingfinal, (select page_display_order + 1 as pdo from `static_pages` order by `page_display_order` desc limit 1), 2014-11-07 15:54:16, 2014-11-07 15:54:16))` which is wrong.

Comment: @siddiq - You might need a table alias. Try the updated answer.

Comment: @JosephSilber Thanks. it worked like a charm. DB::Raw() and Subquery with alias did this. I will mark this as answer :)